# Why is :style on re-frame sometimes used with brackets, with curly brackets, and without anything?

Tags: javascript, css, clojure, clojurescript, re-frame

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Usually, I build the project by executing the command cider-jack-in-cljs in Emacs, choosing shadow-cljs, then shadow for REPL type, and, finally, app for building option.

On the source code of the project we have:

```clj
(defn splitter-panel-title
  [text]
  [title
   :label text
   :level :level3
   :style {:margin-top "20px"}])
```

Notice the `style` without **a direct prefix** of bracket or curly bracket   `:style {:margin-top "20px"}`. Also, in a smaller frequency, we have:

```clj
(defn left-panel
  []
  [box
   :size "auto"
   :child [:div {:style rounded-panel}
           [splitter-panel-title [:code ":panel-1"]]]])
```

Notice the `style` with curly bracket `{:style rounded-panel}`. Finally, we also have:

```clj
(defn header-view []
 [:div
   [:div
    [:style
     {:type "text/css"}]]])
```

Note the bracket `[:style`.

Why is `:style` on re-frame sometimes used with brackets, with curly brackets, and without anything? What is the rule behind the use of each approach?

If my understanding is correct, this is an-inline style in Re-frame. The last two examples are inside a `div` tag. But each of them uses a different approach.

Is the bracket, the curly bracket, and the non-use of bracket connected somehow to Javascript and/or CSS syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the `title` or `box` component will tell you why its done this way. What `reagent/re-frame` will do here is take the `title` component and essentially call it as

```clj
(title :label text :level :level3 :style {:margin-top "20px"})
```

when it is time to render the actual component. So, my guess it that the `title` component uses variadic destructuring like

```
(defn title [& {:keys [...] :as args}] ...)
```

CLJ(S) allow calling functions with key/value pairs like this. So, essentially what arrives it just a map and could have been this:

```
(defn splitter-panel-title
  [text]
  [title
   {:label text
    :level :level3
    :style {:margin-top "20px"}}])
```